# Do ajax calls NOT execute the javascript on the pulled page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an ajax call that pulls data from a page that itself pulls data through an ajax call from another page. But it doesn't seem like the javascript of the second page is executing. Instead its just being brought back without being executed.

Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function LoadAccessList()
    {
        var url = '@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["environmentSite"]/Search/Finish?function=searchAndRetrieve&section=search&step=finish&sourceDataset=Wickliffe&object=accessList&searchType=basic&renderAsPageFragment=true&inputParameter=accessEmail&selectedResultFormat=column&query0=@ViewBag.Email';

        document.getElementById('accessListResult').innerHTML = '<span style="color:#ff0000;font-weight:bold;">Please wait for results...</span>';

        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open('GET', url, true);
        http.onreadystatechange = function ()
        {
            if (http.readyState == 4)
            {
                document.getElementById('accessListResult').innerHTML = http.responseText;
            }
        }
        http.send(null);
    }
</script>

<p>Access List</p>
<div name="accessListResult" id="accessListResult" class="" style="padding-top:20px;"></div>
<script>
    LoadAccessList();
    document.write("afterLoad");
</script>

TESTING 123
```

Calling the second page directly everything executes (relatively) as it should.

Am I going about this the wrong way? I just want the second page to execute to completion then pass its contents back to the first page to render.

Comment: Webpages retrieved via ajax are not loaded/parsed like it was a normally loaded webpage. Javascript doesn't get parsed, resources do not get loaded, etc. If you mean executed after adding it through `innerHTML` that won't work as browsers prevent scripts from executing that are added that way

Comment: It is executed asyncronously. If you want it to wait until have the code has been executed. Perform the actions you want to perform after the success() function in the ajax call. Otherwise it will essentially just skip over that code rather than sit and wait.

Comment: Okay thanks guys. I appreciate the input.